# Call method from class

Tags: angular, typescript, angular6

I want to call a method from a class. I tried this:

```
export class IdGenerator {

  public randomString(): string {
    const length = 40;
    const chars = '0123456789abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ';
    let result = '';
    for (let i = length; i > 0; --i) {
      result += chars[Math.floor(Math.random() * chars.length)];
    }
    return result;
  }
}
```

I call it here:

```
import {IdGenerator} from '@utils/id.generator';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-merchant-new',
  templateUrl: './merchant-new.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./merchant-new.component.scss']
})
export class MerchantNewComponent extends FormBaseComponent {

  formGroup = new FormGroup({
    login: new FormControl(IdGenerator.randomString(), [Validators.required, Validators.maxLength(40)]),
  });

  constructor(private merchantService: MerchantService,
              private router: Router) {
    super();
  }
}
```

But I get error `TS2339: Property 'randomString' does not exist on type 'typeof IdGenerator'.`

What is the proper way to call method and get String?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have defined `randomString` as instance method. So, you have to call it as

```
new IdGenerator().randomString()
```

---

If you want to call it as `IdGenerator.randomString()` then you should define this method as static:

```
export class IdGenerator {

  static randomString(): string {
    ...
  }
}
```

See working example [here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ppppdz)

Comment: Thanks. But which solution will be better for performance? New class every time or static?

Comment: Static method seems to be more efficient. However, Angular stands for dependency injection pattern so in Angular way it's better to use first variant, but you should inject `IdGenerator` through class constructor same as you inject `MerchantService` for example

Comment: You can find both examples here https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ppppdz

Comment: Did it help and you got what I mean?

Comment: You should either add @Injectable with `providedIn 'root'` property (see, as it is done in my example) or add your `IdGenerator` to the list of module providers. First variant is more preferred.

Comment: Well I get empty string for some reason.

Comment: Please, compare with the example in StackBlitz that I've provided above and check for some differences, because the example works as you expect in both variants.

Comment: Well the solution that I have managed to run is to use static method. Thanks.